# LWJGL Quad rendering issues - an object that is meant to be a square is coming out as a rectangle

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

My problem is that I am rendering a quad with opengl. This code:

```
public void render() {
    System.out.println("Test");
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glTranslated(300,300,0);


    GL11.glColor3f(1f, 1f,1f);
    GL11.glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 1);
    GL11.glScalef(64, 64, 0);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glVertex2i(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2i(0, 1);
    GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

This should appear as a nice clean square as the size is 64x64, although it appears like this.
[image]

Whats odd about this I have drawn correctly an image behind it which is fine. I have stopped drawing this image/quad and it still causes the same problem. I cannot see any problem with the code above.

If this snippet of code comes in handy this is my OpenGl initialization code:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 720, 0, 1280, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Just now I tested it in another lwjgl configuration and it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is aspect ratio problem.You should take care of this in your glOrtho() method.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071814/opengl-stretched-shapes-aspect-ratio) is what you need.Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338729/preserve-aspect-ratio-of-2d-object-on-window-resize) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498784/keeping-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-in-opengl) one.More web search would do the trick without asking it here ;)

Also,try gluOrtho instead.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891977/aspect-ratio-stretching-in-opengl) answer.

Comment: Okay, I had a play around with your first link and all it game me is:[link](http://puu.sh/4lf8E.png) but I will continue to search on the web to find out how to fix the aspect ratio problem. Thank you for alerting it to me.

Comment: Thanks, gluOrtho looks like it was what I needed in the circumstances. I'll try and replace all deprecated code to remove this issue. It is a shame I cannot up-vote you :(